# How to parse JSON and put 2 fields in dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to parse JSON file and get two fields from the JSON and put them in a dictionary. For example:

```
{
    "food": [{
            "name": "pasta",
            "type": "blabla",
            "sauce": [{
                    "name": "cream",
                    "url": "http://www...."
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "name": "pizza",
            "type": "bla",
            "sauce": [{
                    "name": "Tomato",
                    "url": "http://www...."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to get:

```
{pasta: cream, pizza: Tomato}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dict comprehension`can do the job:

```
data = {
    "food": [{
            "name": "pasta",
            "type": "blabla",
            "sauce": [{
                    "name": "cream",
                    "url": "http://www...."
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "name": "pizza",
            "type": "bla",
            "sauce": [{
                    "name": "Tomato",
                    "url": "http://www...."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

foods = data['food']
print( {food['name']:food['sauce'][0]['name'] for food in foods})
```

Comment: if the json is in another file or string format, you'd have to use `json.load(file)` or `json.loads(string)`: something like `import json; json.load("foods.json")`

Comment: "food": [{ "name": "pasta", "type": "blabla", "sauce": [{ "name": "cream", "url": "http://www...." } { "name": "Tomato", "url": "http://www...." } ] }, { "name": "pizza", "type": "bla", "sauce": [{ "name": "Tomato", "url": "http://www...." } ] } ] }

And if I add another sauce and I want to get: {pasta: cream Tomato, pizza: Tomato}